# Issue Starting MySQL Daemon

Tags: mysql, daemon, dedicated-server

I have just come across the most random error I've seen my MySQL daemon spew out yet, everything was working fine, then all of a sudden it randomly crashed and it now outputting this when I start it up, not sure if it's because my 'my.cnf' file is minimal

Here's my 'my.cnf':

```
[mysqld]
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mysqld according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd
datadir=/var/lib/mysql/
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Here's the errors:

```
120817  3:47:26 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
120817  3:47:26 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120817  3:47:26 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
120817  3:47:26 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
120817  3:47:26 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
120817  3:47:26 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120817  3:47:26 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: auto-extending data file ./ibdata1 is of a different size
InnoDB: 384 pages (rounded down to MB) than specified in the .cnf file:
InnoDB: initial 640 pages, max 0 (relevant if non-zero) pages!
120817  3:47:26 InnoDB: Could not open or create data files.
120817  3:47:26 InnoDB: If you tried to add new data files, and it failed here,
120817  3:47:26 InnoDB: you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back
120817  3:47:26 InnoDB: to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created
120817  3:47:26 InnoDB: in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of
120817  3:47:26 InnoDB: zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not
120817  3:47:26 InnoDB: remove old data files which contain your precious data!
120817  3:47:26 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
120817  3:47:26 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
120817  3:47:26 [ERROR] mysqld: unknown variable 'max_used_connections=0'
120817  3:47:26 [ERROR] Aborting

120817  3:47:26 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks guys! :D

Comment: Are you starting as root? But voting to move - not a programming question

Comment: No I was starting it as the MySQL user.

Comment: Fro those who have this problem with docker container:
[github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/99](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/99)
or
[docker-with-mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249719/docker-with-mysql-the-error-means-mysqld-does-not-have-the-access-rights-to-the)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd be better off asking this in a server forum than progrmming forum?

I ***think*** you can delete the ibdata1 files safely and they get rebuilt, but to be sure **rename** the ibdata1 file(s) and restart MySQL. If that fails, rename it back and go to the right place ;)

If it does work, run mysqlcheck (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html) and/or possibly export all data as SQL (mysqldump), wipe the entire database and re-import from the dump file.

Comment: Nope, didn't work, the databases now contain no tables :/ So even if I do a dump it doesn't output code to create the tables that I had.

Answer (score 1):

Could be value of innodb_data_file_path got changed. Check your /etc/mysql/conf.d/* files.

If not specified otherwise, the default is

```
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
```